# How to use SetThreadPreferredUILanguages?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, locale

I am currently working on a locale issue caused by Migrating to Windows 7, as `SetThreadLocale()` is not supported for Windows 7. This has caused the issue of not being able to display text with another language other than the default.

[image: language displaying issue]

I understand instead of using the first one, the second should be used
[image: functions used]

But this is giving a problem

- It gives "identifier not found" even though the header files are included

My questions are:

- What are the correct arguments to be supplied to the second and third parameters if my goal is to simply change the locale?
- On the MSDN website, it mentioned about the Kernal32.dll. Am I supposed to do something about that?
- What is your suggestion on toggling this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that `WINVER` (and `_WIN32_WINNT` also)  is defined with `0x0600` or above.

`#define WINVER 0x0600`

Check `WinNIs.h` header where these functions are *conditionally* defined.

For versions and these macros, refer this page:

[Modifying WINVER and _WIN32_WINNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx)